# Mongodb update conditional set operator ($set only when it is insert )

Tags: mongodb, update

Is there anything in Mongo update where $set when will work only when an insert is done.

example is  I have a collection which has these fields:

1. Username
2. FirstOccurrence
3. Count

What i want that i will run a update operation like this.

```
coll.update{ q: {username} ,u: {$set:{FirstOccurrence},$inc:count} }
```

But condition will be if UserName is already existing then it wont run the $set it will just increment the count.

Is it possible to do it I am running Mongo 2.6.4 with Java driver 2.13.0

Regards
Viren

Answer (score 5):

It will work for conditional $set update operation

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

```
db.products.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  {
    $set: { item: "apple" },
    $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }
  },
  {upsert: true }
)
```

Here setOnInsert will set defaultQty only when a new record is inserted.
Both $set and $setOnInsert can be used together.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Colin'tHart have added an example to it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You have not answered the question. The questions asked about $inc which you missed